# How to have multiple AuthUserFile directive in proftpd.conf

Tags: ftp, authentication

In my CentOS where CPanel is installed in proftpd.conf, I can see directive

```
AuthUserFile /etc/proftpd/passwd.vhosts
```

I wanted to add one more `AuthUserFile` directive, so Profptd uses one more file to lookup users beside `/etc/proftpd/passwd.vhosts`
so I added one more line below `AuthUserFile`

```
AuthUserFile /home/public_html/cgi-bin/ftp/ftp.users
```

but it seems it is not using my new AuthUserFile directive

Can anyone help me to how to make Proftpd look in another file for users besides this one `/etc/proftpd/passwd.vhosts`

---

As you suggested, I added this in proftpd.conf and started Proftpd daemon in debug mode, but still it is not using this file.

```
<VirtualHost www8.example.com>
  ServerName                    "www8.example.com's FTP Server"

  MaxClients                    40
  MaxLoginAttempts              3


  DeferWelcome                  on

  AuthUserFile /home/xxx/public_html/cgi-bin/ftp/ftp.users

</VirtualHost>
```

here is the debug log:

```
- dispatching CMD command 'AUTH TLS' to mod_tls
 - dispatching LOG_CMD command 'AUTH TLS' to mod_log
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_tls
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_core
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_delay
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_auth
 - dispatching CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_auth
 - dispatching POST_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_delay
 - dispatching LOG_CMD command 'USER testuser' to mod_log
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_tls
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_core
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_wrap
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_delay
 - dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
 - dispatching CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
 - mod_auth_file/0.9: using passwd file '/etc/proftpd/passwd.vhosts'
 - USER testuser: no such user found from 117.x.x.x
```

Comment: I've expanded my answer with some information about why the VirtualHost-solution may not work

Comment: I know there is a solution for this coz i have done this in past like 2 years ago on same server but now i don't remember what directive i used and how i did it

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AuthUserFile.html) you can have multiple `AuthUserFile`-directives if you have them in different VirtualHosts.
It doesn't appear to me that what you're doing is supported.

There are other ways to achieve what you are trying to:

- merge the two files (manually or automatically by cron for example)
- use another authentication method for proftpd

  - see their [FAQ](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch7.html#AEN709) for a full list.
  - proftpd uses system users by default together with the file specified in `AuthUserFile`. This is configured by [`AuthOrder`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AuthOrder.html)

You may also look into using VirtualHosts, but you have to be aware of [how they work](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Vhost.html):

> The definition of the File Transfer Protocol, unfortunately, does not (currently) support name-based virtual hosts, as HTTP1.1 supports. All FTP virtual hosts are based on unique IP address/port combinations, not on DNS names. The similarity of ProFTPD's configuration file syntax to Apache's sometimes leads users to assuming that proftpd will handle these the same way -- but more on this later. The bottom line is that ProFTPD does not support name-based virtual hosts; not because they are not implemented, but simply because the protocol itself does not support them.